# Godot4 arrays fail to add elements

Tags: c#, arrays, godot, godot4

Godot.Collections.Array2D creates error when I try to add a new element to it

```
private void SpawnPieces()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
        {
            Random random = new();
            int num = random.Next(possiblePieces.Count() - 1);
            Node2D sceneInstance = possiblePieces[num].Instantiate() as Node2D;
            AddChild(sceneInstance);
            sceneInstance.Position = GridToPixel(i, j);
            piecesArray[i][j].Append(sceneInstance);

        }
    }
}
```

piecesArray is initialised in this way

```
Godot.Collections.Array<Node2D>[][] piecesArray;
```

The error is the following

```
E 0:00:01:0019   void Grid2.SpawnPieces(): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  <C# Error>     System.NullReferenceException
  <C# Source>    Grid2.cs:73 @ void Grid2.SpawnPieces()
  <Stack Trace>  Grid2.cs:73 @ void Grid2.SpawnPieces()
                 Grid2.cs:37 @ void Grid2._Ready()
                 Node.cs:2117 @ bool Godot.Node.InvokeGodotClassMethod(Godot.NativeInterop.godot_string_name&, Godot.NativeInterop.NativeVariantPtrArgs, Godot.NativeInterop.godot_variant&)
                 CanvasItem.cs:1370 @ bool Godot.CanvasItem.InvokeGodotClassMethod(Godot.NativeInterop.godot_string_name&, Godot.NativeInterop.NativeVariantPtrArgs, Godot.NativeInterop.godot_variant&)
                 Node2D.cs:522 @ bool Godot.Node2D.InvokeGodotClassMethod(Godot.NativeInterop.godot_string_name&, Godot.NativeInterop.NativeVariantPtrArgs, Godot.NativeInterop.godot_variant&)
                 Grid2_ScriptMethods.generated.cs:78 @ bool Grid2.InvokeGodotClassMethod(Godot.NativeInterop.godot_string_name&, Godot.NativeInterop.NativeVariantPtrArgs, Godot.NativeInterop.godot_variant&)
                 CSharpInstanceBridge.cs:24 @ Godot.NativeInterop.godot_bool Godot.Bridge.CSharpInstanceBridge.Call(nint, Godot.NativeInterop.godot_string_name*, Godot.NativeInterop.godot_variant**, int, Godot.NativeInterop.godot_variant_call_error*, Godot.NativeInterop.godot_variant*)
```

The array should append the Node2D sceneInstance but it doesn't work, I tried several times to change the way of how I construct the array, I tried to instantiate again the instance, assign it to a specific position but nothing works, everything works fine and how it should be if I comment the line piecesArray[i][j].Append(sceneInstance);

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. The tag information shouldn't be there at all, and *problem* is meaningless. Your title should e clear and descriptive enough that the post content is clear to a future user skimming a list of search results. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask]. Also, you'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Your Grid2 class needs to be instantiated first before calling SpawnPieces() on it

Comment: @TP95 my function SpawnPieces() is inside the Grid2 class
I just tried to return the array instead of assign it, but it doesn't work

Comment: @GiuseppeSposito can you show the code where Grid2.SpawnPieces() is being called? Right now the question has only the code inside the SpawnPieces method